# Does this protocol description and design look sound?

Tags: symmetric, protocol-analysis, password-based-encryption, notation

I am working on a tool that uses password derived keys for AES and a selectable modes of operation **to encrypt (and later decrypt) text for storage on an insecure media**. The tool is constrained to using only the functions provided by the browser [SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) API, which are described as "low-level cryptographic primitives that are very easy to misuse". The protocol below seems simple/typical, but I'd like to describe it more formally and ask if I've designed this well or not. Questions:

1. How can I make the description below closer to what people in this field expect?
2. What is the mathematical notation for array slicing. For example, in python `a[:128]`. Perhaps submatrix notation `a[1;1...128]`?
3. Do you see problems with the protocol?

**~~Updated based on comments~~**

**Agents**
$A$ - Alice
$S$ - Browser with SubtleCrypto API
$R$ - https://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=32
$D$ - Insecure persistent storage system

**Browser Functions**
$E_O$ - AES-256 cipher in mode of operation o
$K$ - PBKDF2 512 bit key derivation function using SHA-512
$H$ - 256 bit FIPS 198-1 HMAC tag generator
$V$ - 256 bit FIPS 198-1 HMAC tag validator
$P$ - Cryptographically strong pseudo random generator

**Values**
$m$ - Clear text message
$p$ - Clear text password
$c$ - Encrypted text
$t$ - 256 bit HMAC tag
$b$ - Valid or invalid HMAC tag
$i$ - PBKDF2 iteration count (minimum 800,000)
$o$ - Block cipher mode of operation (GCM, CBC, CTR)
$r$ - 256 bits of true or pseudo random data
$n_{IV}$ - 128 bit true or pseudo random initialization vector
$n_S$ - 128 bit true or pseudo random salt
$d$ - 512 bits of derived key material
$k_C$ - 256 bit cipher key
$k_S$ - 256 bit signing key

**Message Encryption by A**
$A \rightarrow S : m, p, i, o\\
S\textrm{ computes}:\\
\hspace{10pt}r = P(256) \lor S \overset{\textrm{https}}{\leftarrow} R\\
\hspace{10pt}n_S = r[0:128)\\
\hspace{10pt}n_{IV} = r[128:256)\\
\hspace{10pt}d = K(p, n_S, i)\\
\hspace{10pt}k_C = d[0:256)\\
\hspace{10pt}k_S = d[256:512)\\
\hspace{10pt}c = E_O(m, n_{IV}, k_C)\\
\hspace{10pt}t = H( c \mathbin\Vert n_{IV} \mathbin\Vert n_S \mathbin\Vert o \mathbin\Vert i, k_S)\\
S \rightarrow A: t \mathbin\Vert c \mathbin\Vert  n_{IV} \mathbin\Vert n_S \mathbin\Vert o \mathbin\Vert i$

**Message Storage by A**
$A \rightarrow D: t \mathbin\Vert c \mathbin\Vert n_{IV} \mathbin\Vert n_S \mathbin\Vert o \mathbin\Vert i$

**Message Decryption by A**
$A \leftarrow D:  t \mathbin\Vert c \mathbin\Vert  n_{IV} \mathbin\Vert n_S \mathbin\Vert o \mathbin\Vert i\\
A \rightarrow S:  p , t \mathbin\Vert c \mathbin\Vert  n_{IV} \mathbin\Vert n_S \mathbin\Vert o \mathbin\Vert i\\
S\textrm{ computes}:\\
\hspace{10pt}d = K(p, n_S, i)\\
\hspace{10pt}k_C = d[0:256)\\
\hspace{10pt}k_S = d[256:512)\\
\hspace{10pt}b = V( c \mathbin\Vert n_{IV} \mathbin\Vert n_S \mathbin\Vert o \mathbin\Vert i, k_S, t)\\
\hspace{10pt}\textrm{if }b:\\
\hspace{10pt}\hspace{10pt}m = E_O^{-1}(c, n_{IV}, k_C)\\
S \rightarrow A : b, m\textrm{ if }b$

Comment: Well, it's certainly PBE with authenticated encryption and you didn't forget to HMAC the parameters for that. You did seem to forget to use them in GCM mode and it is weird that you don't allow GCM mode as an authenticated option *next to* the HMAC over CBC or CTR. However, this is not a full answer which is one reason why these kind of reviews are off topic.

Comment: Nice protocol description though. I would probably remove $A$ or $S$ as an entity as Alice seems to encrypt for herself. Also the letter $S$ is now both an entity *and* a function. I'd introduce a variable for the result of the PBKDF as it seems now like it needs to be performed twice. Maybe a reason for the order of the output could be indicated, quite often the order is nonce/IV, then the ciphertext and finally the tag (and the additional authenticated data could maybe be put between the IV and the ciphertext). The GCM seal uses IV | ciphertext | tag.

Comment: Nothing wrong with in place encryption though, if performed deliberately. One issue I have with SIV mode is that it places the IV / tag in front of the ciphertext which makes in place encryption impossible.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks. GCM mode is supported for the mode of operation (see description after variable 'o'. If GCM is selected the protocol may do double tagging (once by GCM and once by HMAC). I should probably remove that and only do HMAC for CBC and CTR. The actual code does only one PBKDF and splits the resulting bits, so I'll update the description as you suggested.